# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.SearchResource.ListRequest.OrderEnum?'

Tags: c#, youtube-data-api

I have looked and looked for about two hours now for an answer to this error while using the YouTube data API. No matter what, this error will not go away except when casting or using "0" (no other number works and I know it does something because the results change with the 0). However, when I cast it to an enum the error goes away and then the YouTube server claims this value does not exist.

```
        var searchListRequest = YoutubeService.Search.List("snippet");
        searchListRequest.Q = "Android";
        searchListRequest.MaxResults = 50;
        searchListRequest.Order = "viewCount";
        //searchListRequest.Order = (SearchResource.ListRequest.OrderEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(SearchResource.ListRequest.OrderEnum),"date");
        searchListRequest.RelevanceLanguage = "en";
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? It also happens with other values in the YouTube API as well (anything that's an enum).

I was thinking if I can't fix it then I should probably just use GET requests from the site.

Edit: Thanks Chris Dunway!

Comment: Please add the code used to the post. It makes it easier for others to help:)

Comment: Firstly, please post your code _as text_ in your question and not as an image.  An image cannot be searched by others.  The error is clear.  You are trying to assign a `string` to a variable of an enum type.  Try something like this:  `searchListRequest.Order =  Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.SearchResource.ListRequest.OrderEnum.ViewCount`.  Please see [this link](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1YouTube_1_1v3_1_1SearchResource_1_1ListRequest.html#a8952679200ee5d18c7b8e89cdc67b8e7) for the documentation.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Thanks and yes in the future I will keep this in mind. First time ever actually having to post something. As for asking, yes I know it's clear form the error but the other YouTube documentation that Google has for C# on GitHub stated it was a string. Just a little confusion. Also thanks for that other link!

Comment: You can still update your post with the text version of the code by using the edit link at the bottom left.  You should do that when you have a chance.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway sure thing